# Send SMS from application with concatenated Text

Tags: android, smsmanager

I am confused. My application will not send if sms message has concatenated text, why?

It's Work:

```
receiver = 99999;  
SmsHelper smsHelper = new SmsHelper(ctx);
smsHelper.sendSMS(receiver, "IT'S WORK!");
```

Don't Work with concatenated text.

```
  receiver = 99999;
  String text1 = "NOT";
  String text2 = "WORKING";
  String smsFullText = text1.concat(text2);
  SmsHelper smsHelper = new SmsHelper(ctx);
  smsHelper.sendSMS(receiver, smsFullText);
```

my SmsHelper.class

```
public class SmsHelper{

private static final String ACTION_SEND = "SMS_SEND";
private static final String ACTION_RECEIVED = "SMS_RECEIVED";

private Context ctx;
private String text;



   public SmsHelper(Context ctx){
     this.ctx = ctx;
   }

   public void sendSMS(String Receiver, String Sms){
   this.text = Sms;
   PendingIntent peitSend = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx,0,new Intent(ACTION_SEND),0);
    PendingIntent peitReceived = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, new Intent(ACTION_RECEIVED), 0);

    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(Receiver,null,text, peitSend, peitReceived);
   }

}
```

Comment: i check your code! its working fine. What you passing in ctx? i tried with both getApplicationContext() and ActivityName.this and its working.

Comment: Hi. I passing one context in one Fragment because the SmsHelper class is non activity. This code send sms with concatenated text???              String text1 = "NOT";
  String text2 = "WORKING";
  String smsFullText = text1.concat(text2);

Comment: I found my problem. The problem is text with especial character. Without especial character(áéã) the sms limit is 160 characters. With especial characters the sms limit is only 70..